# AngularJS toggle ng-repeat visibility with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, filter

So I have a list of notices in AngularJS which I create with `ng-repeat`.  The notices have a visibility status which determines whether the notice is shown in the list.  Every notice has controls which allow that notice to be hidden, a simple button that changes the `notice.status.visibility` to false.

I also have a checkbox input that is supposed to show hidden notices. However, I am unsure on how to implement this and how would it work.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Show Hidden" />
    <li ng-repeat="notice on notices | filter: filter.search">
        <div ng-show="notice.status.visibility">
            <!-- notice details -->
        </div>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe with something like this:

```
<ul>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Show Hidden" ng-model="showHidden" />
    <li ng-repeat="notice on notices | filter: filter.search">
        <div ng-show="showHidden || notice.status.visibility">
            <!-- notice details -->
        </div>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Obviously my guestion was way too simple :D Thank you!